# suspend and unsuspend don't want to cache in cPanel

Tags: caching, cpanel, varnish, purge

I used varnish cache in backend server with cPanel,  I want suspend and unsuspend requests in WHM be done in a moment and suspend or unsuspend requests (and page) Don't cache...

What setting should be made on the varnish side?

Answer (score 0):

You should add custom script in /scripts in WHM server...